# How to use only the moves of a white piece in board-output and chess-annotation

Tags: chessboard, xskak

[image]

Is there a way to capture and display just the moves of a white piece, in both board-output AND chess-annotation? 
If possible without the three placeholder dots.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{chessboard, xskak}
%\setchessboard{showmover=false, }

\begin{document}
\newchessgame[id=MyGame, 
setwhite={Ke4},
%hideblack,
]
\mainline{1. Ke3 ... 2. Kd3 ... 3. Ke4 ... 4. Ke5}

\chessboard[id=MyGame,]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used

```
\makeatletter
\def\xskak@do@printmove{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\xskak@val@player}{b}}{}{\xskakget{san}\xskakget{nag}}}
```

so:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{chessboard, xskak}
\setchessboard{showmover=false}

\begin{document}
\newchessgame[id=MyGame, setwhite={Ke4}]
\hidemoves{1. Ke3 ... 2. Kd3 ... 3. Ke4 ... 4. Ke5}
\chessboard

\makeatletter
\def\xskak@do@printmove{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\xskak@val@player}{b}}{}{\xskakget{san}\xskakget{nag}}}

\section*{style=UF}
\printchessgame[style=UF]
\section*{style=styleC}
\printchessgame[id=MyGame, style=styleC]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Please, take the following with a grain of salt, as I'm definitely not an expert in these packages.]

The way in which the packages [skak](https://ctan.org/pkg/skak?lang=en) and [xskak](https://ctan.org/pkg/xskak?lang=en) operate requires that there is a "mainline" of moves, forming the progression of a game, from some starting position. This is important because, at any point in time, the board's state can be built from the starting position, performing the "mainline" of moves.

Unfortunately, in the "mainline" you cannot omit the black's moves, or it wouldn't be possible to build the board's state.

What you can do, however, is to add dummy moves for the black (as you already did, leaving them unspecified as `...`) and making sure you do not print them. The command `\whitemainline` that I'm defining below does exactly this. It was inspired from [the documentation](https://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/xskak/xskak.pdf) of package `xskak`, v.1.5, p.35.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{chessboard,xskak}
\newcommand\whitemainline[1]{%
  \edef\thegameid{\xskakgetgame{gameid}}%
  \edef\themoveid{\xskakget{moveid}}%
  \hidemoves{#1}%
  \mainlinestyle%
  \xskakset{id=\thegameid,moveid=\themoveid}%
  \whiledo{\xskaktestmoveid{\xskakget{movenr}}{\xskakget{player}}}%
          {\xskakget{movenr}\,\xskakget{san}%
           \hspace{.5em}\xskakset{stepmoveid=2}}}
\begin{document}
\newchessgame[id=MyGame,setwhite={Ke4}]
\whitemainline{1. Ke3 ... 2. Kd3 ... 3. Ke4 ... 4. Ke5 ...}
\par
\chessboard[id=MyGame,showmover=false]

\bigskip

\whitemainline{5. Kf5 ... 6. Kg6}
\par
\chessboard[id=MyGame,showmover=false]
\end{document}
```

This produces the following:

[image]

Two notes:

1. I removed the black box indicating it's the black's turn (`showmover=false`) because I think it doesn't make much sense in your setting. If you want it, you have to make sure that your moves stop with a white's move and then continue with a black's move:

   ```
   \whitemainline{1. Ke3 ... 2. Kd3 ... 3. Ke4 ... 4. Ke5}
   ...
   \whitemainline{4... ... 5. Kf5 ... 6. Kg6}
   ```
2. If you want to omit the dummy black moves entirely and have something like:

   ```
   \whitemainline{1. Ke3 2. Kd3 3. Ke4 4. Ke5}
   ```

   then you will have to do some parsing of the moves and introduce the
   dummy black moves inside `\whitemainline`. This can be a lot trickier, depending on the subset of the PGN notation that you want to support.

Comment: Interesting! I noticed that this no longer works for different styles. I had the idea of ​​putting a \vphantom in the font or in the beforeblack key. But I was not able to make that work.

Comment: It's not working with different styles because of the hardwired `\xskakget{movenr}\,\xskakget{san}` in the loop. You can change that. Using '\vphantom` would work, but you'd have to break the mainline manually.