# chessboard / xskak: How to add a move-number '0.' at the chess-annotation

Tags: chess, chessboard, xskak

Is is possibe to get a "Startposition" / "Number 0" in the move-annotation-printout?

If I try `\hidemoves{0. Ke4 ...  1. Ke3 ... }`
I get the error `! mainline: 0 is not the correct move number.`
`

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{chessboard, xskak}
\setchessboard{showmover=false}
% For hiding the black pieces annotation =====
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/634522/46023
\makeatletter
\def\xskak@do@printmove{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\xskak@val@player}{b}}{}{\xskakget{san}\xskakget{nag}}}
% =============================

\begin{document}
\newchessgame[id=MyGame, 
setwhite={Ke4}% Startposition ----> " 0. Ke4 " 
]
\hidemoves{%0. Ke4 ...  --> not allowed
1. Ke3 ... 2. Kd3 ... 3. Ke4 ... 4. Ke5}
\chessboard

\printchessgame[style=styleC]

\printchessgame[style=UF]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
\xskakset{defaultmovenr=0,}
```

so:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=10mm]{geometry}
%\documentclass[margin=5mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{chessboard, xskak}
\setchessboard{showmover=false, margin=false}
\xskakset{defaultmovenr=0,}
% For hiding the black pieces annotation =====
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/634522/46023
\makeatletter
\def\xskak@do@printmove{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\xskak@val@player}{b}}{}{\xskakget{san}\xskakget{nag}}}
% alternativ: 
%\renewcommand\xskak@val@defaultmovenr{0}
\makeatother
% =============================

\begin{document}
\newchessgame[id=MyGame, 
setwhite={Ka4}% Startposition 
]
\hidemoves{0. Ke4 ... 
1. Ke3 ... 2. Kd3 ... 3. Ke4 ... 4. Ke5}
%\chessboard[]
%\printchessgame[style=styleC]

\foreach \MoveNo in {0,...,4}{%%
\begin{tcbitemize}[sharp corners, raster equal height=rows,
raster column skip=0mm,
boxrule=1.2pt, boxsep=5mm, 
colback=white, colbacktitle=white,  coltitle=black, fonttitle=\bfseries,
]
\tcbitem[title={Position \MoveNo}] \chessboard[
movenr=\MoveNo, player=w, setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}] 
\tcbitem[] \printchessgame[style=styleC]
\end{tcbitemize}
}%%
\end{document}
```